# Call to a member function adverts() on integer

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I have a morphMany relationship and trying to save data to the pivot table using ajax but getting this error

> "Call to a member function adverts() on integer"

My ajax code

```
function onBookmark()
{

$recordId = post('bookmark');

$record = Advert::find($recordId);

$user=  Auth::getUser()->id;

$user->adverts()->syncWithoutDetaching($record);

return Redirect::back();


}
```

Comment: You probably ment to call it on the user-object? If so, replace `$user=  Auth::getUser()->id;` with `$user = Auth::getUser();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the `id` for the user which will return an integer not the instance of the User model.

Instead try changing the following line from this

```php
$user = Auth::getUser()->id;
```

to this:

```php
$user = Auth::getUser();
```